# Members seen as functions when using `this` keyword?

Tags: solidity

Lately I'm getting an error when using

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

contract Contract {

    uint256 private member;

    constructor (uint256 _member) {
        this.member = _member;
    }
}
```

linter would complain `Member "member" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Contract.`, but when I change member's visibility to `public`, it says `Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type function () view external returns (uint256).` To get the expected behaviour I have to ommit `this` and just use `member = _member`.

It seems as `this` makes the contract view its members as those from another contract. Is this a problem with the linter or is it compiler version specific (as it didn't happen before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems as this makes the contract view its members as those from another contract.

That's exactly how it works, yeah. If you want to access your private variable from within your contract, just use its name directly. Adding the `this.` prefix makes it do an external call to itself) instead, making it so you can call external functions (which you wouldnt be able to do without using `this.`) but can't access private/internal variables/functions anymore.

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation :

> The getter functions have external visibility. If the symbol is
> accessed internally (i.e. without this.), it evaluates to a state
> variable. If it is accessed externally (i.e. with this.), it evaluates
> to a function.

So you are trying to assign to the getter when using the this keyword. And the getter is automatically created for public state variables.